# ApiAiApp is not a constructor

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am testing below node.js client library with api.ai, I copied the exact code from the example given by on this page.

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ApiAiApp

But every time I am getting

```
TypeError: ApiAiApp is not a constructor
 at /app/index.js:9:15
 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Here's my index.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var exps = express();

const ApiAiApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;

exps.post('/hook', function(request, response) {

  const app = new ApiAiApp({request, response});

  response.status(200)
  response.json({
      speech: "Hello from hook",
      displayText: "Hello from hook",
      source: 'HOOK'
  })
  console.log("RESPONSE :::: \n");
  console.log(response);
});

exps.listen((process.env.PORT || 8000), function() {
    console.log("App up and running, listening.")
})
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "googleActionNode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Sukhvinder Singh",
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "1.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sukhvinder1/googleActionNode.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sukhvinder1/googleActionNode/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sukhvinder1/googleActionNode#readme"
}
```

if I commnent out below line, everything works fine.

```
  const app = new ApiAiApp({request: request, response: response});
```

Can anyone please help me here ?

Comment: just before you try calling new on it, see if you can do a console.log(ApiAiApp); and console.log(typeof ApiAiApp);

Comment: Also post your package.json and what version of actions-on-google you're using

Comment: I've deleted my answer thanks to @Prisoner who point me into the right docs. I would go with his ideas on how to debug it in order to make it work.

Comment: @Prisoner, I was using actions-on-google v 1.0.0 before. Now I have updated it to 1.2.0, which solved the problem. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Glad it helped! @IdoGreen has the better answer now, which was updated to reflect the details of your problem. If you can upvote and accept the answer, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Prisoner, I  am new to Dialogflow and am facing quite the similar error. I am not sure how am I supposed to update the actions on google version. Can you help  me please?

Comment: @Khush - That is probably best asked as a new question in SO, with you providing the same sorts of information provided here - code that causes the problem, the error that is produced, and your package.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling a method that is not part of actions-on-google for the version you were originally using.

In version 1.0, you would have called it in this way:

```
 const Assistant = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiAssistant;
```

Later versions changed this to

```
 const Assistant = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;
```

Later versions still allow the earlier name, but it has been deprecated and you should switch to both the new name and the most recent library version.

Btw, you might want to take a look at this example that I wrote: https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action/blob/master/index.js 
It shows the way we wish to work with actions-on-google (e.g. using a Map to connect the actions to the intents).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things in that file that are confusing to me, and I wonder if it is confusing node.js as well.

- You shouldn't need to create the definition for both `ActionsSdkApp` and `ApiAiApp`. I would try eliminating the ActionsSdkApp one and see if that works.
- You shouldn't need to call `status()` or `json()` (for a `res` object that I don't think exists in this version of the file).
- The line numbers don't match up, but I'll assume there are other things that could be confounding the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've just edited my question. I hope it's not very confusing now. 
However, I am still getting same error.